# View types in pokemon ruby

Tags: pokemon-ruby-sapphire-emerald

How can I see what type a pokemon is in the pkmn ruby pokedex? I can only see the types of the pokemon in my party.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According to Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9dex#Generation_III), FireRed and LeafGreen (which were released after Ruby) were the first games in which the Pokédex included species' types in their entries.  Thus, you cannot view a Pokémon's types in the Ruby Pokédex.